# ACF Query result in a new td (echo)

Tags: plugins, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I want to save every query result inside a new td in this tr, but somehow it didn't work. I also made `<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>` at the end of the table. It gives me HTTP 500 Error.

```
<tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "Levesek" ?>
                    </td>
                    <?php
                    $args3 = array(
                      'post_type' => 'etlap',
                      'post__in' => $ids,);

                    $query3 = new WP_Query( $args3 );
                    ?>
                    <?php if ($query3->have_posts()): ?>
                        <?php while($query3->have_posts()): ?>
                            <?php $query3->the_post();?>
                                <?php $levesek = get_field('levesek'); ?>
                                    <?php if($levesek): ?>
                                        <?php foreach ($levesek as $leves): ?>
                                            <?php setup_postdata($leves)?>
                    <td><?php echo $leves->post_title;?></td>
                                        <?php endforeach;?>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </tr>
```

Comment: what is the result of the code? what is the content of the array `$ids`? you have `$query3` but you are using `$args2` - did you mean to use `$args3` ?

Comment: Changed to `$args3` but I have a same problem

Comment: what is the result? what is the content of `$ids`?

Comment: http 500 error. Well now I just only use 'post_type' => 'etlap' as array.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it. The final code is:

```
        <?php
    $args2 = array('post_type' => 'etlap',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post__in' => $ids,
        'order' => 'post__in');

    $query2 = new WP_Query($args2);
    ?>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo "Levesek" ?>
                </td>
                <?php if ($query2->have_posts()): ?>
                    <?php while ($query2->have_posts()): ?>
                        <?php $query2->the_post(); ?>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            $levesek = get_field('levesek');
                            $leves_adag = get_field('leves_adag');
                            ?>
                            <?php if ($levesek): ?>
                                <?php foreach ($levesek as $leves): ?>
                                    <?php setup_postdata($leves); ?>
                                    <?php echo $leves->post_title; ?>
                                    <?php $description = do_shortcode('[woo-product-shortcodes id="' . $leves->ID . '" data_attribute="short_description"]'); ?>
                                    <br><?php echo $description; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if ($leves_adag == 0): ?>
                                <br><?php echo "Elfogyott"; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if ($leves_adag != 0): ?>
                                <br><?php echo $leves_adag; ?>
                                <?php $product = new WC_Product('.$leves->ID.'); ?>
                                <?php if ($product->is_type('simple')): ?>
                                    <br><?php echo "Szipla (vĂˇsĂˇrlĂˇs beillesztĂ©se folyamatban)"; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if ($product->is_type('variable')): ?>
                                    <br><?php echo "VariĂˇlhatĂł (vĂˇsĂˇrlĂˇs beillesztĂ©se folyamatban)"; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
```